# mysql where clause dosnt work

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i have this MySQL query to retrieve some data just for those who have language = 3

```
  SELECT
  noor_content.id,noor_content.body,noor_content.category,noor_content.introtext,noor_content.title,noor_content.keywords,noor_content.language,path 
  FROM (`noor_content`) 
  join noor_categories 
  on (noor_content.category = noor_categories.id) 
  WHERE `language` = '3' 
  AND noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%'
```

Problem: the query retrieved those data that have another language but i mentioned language='3'

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: use `WHERE language = 3 
  AND (noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put conditions in brackets.

```
 SELECT noor_content.id,noor_content.body,noor_content.category,noor_content.introtext,noor_content.title,noor_content.keywords,noor_content.language,path 
  FROM (`noor_content`) 
  join noor_categories 
  on (noor_content.category = noor_categories.id) 
  WHERE (`language` = '3' )
  AND ((noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%') 
  or (noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%') 
  or (noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%' ));
```

Comment: Hey Jai tnx man, after i found my first prob, you did answer my second prob. actually i used for loop and i have if and elseif condition and you did answer my sec prob by double (( after AND.

Comment: it is best practice to use brackets for each condition. They can be segregated easily. \

Answer (score 2):

You have to put bracket for `AND` and `OR`condition to satisfy your condition like below

```
 WHERE `language` = '3' 
  AND (noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
  or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so your `WHERE` clause is being interpreted as:

```
WHERE (language = 3 AND noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%')
OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%'
```

The language test is only combined with the first `LIKE`, not the others. You need to add parentheses:

```
WHERE language = 3 
AND (noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%'
    OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
    OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket for search keywords

```
SELECT noor_content.id,noor_content.body,noor_content.category,noor_content.introtext,noor_content.title,noor_content.keywords,noor_content.language,path 
  FROM `noor_content` 
  join noor_categories 
  on noor_content.category = noor_categories.id
WHERE language = 3 AND 
(noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%' or 
noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%' 
or noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you are using OR operator between conditions so use Brackets() 
like this then try

WHERE `language` = '3' 
AND ( noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سمنگان%' 
OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%جوزجان%'  
OR noor_content.keywords LIKE '%سرپل%' )
```